# How do I programmatically get what Chrome shows in the Network Tab?

Tags: python, google-chrome, networking

If you visit a page with the chrome inspector open, you'll see a number of items load in the Network tab. I'd like to programmatically access this content. How do I do that? My google fu is failing here.

My reason for doing this is that each of the pages has a flash swf that I'd like to find the source for. If using a packet sniffer is best, then what's the best way to hook that up to the query itself (which is also going to be programmatic)?

Comment: What's you're probably looking for is a [network/packet sniffer](https://www.google.com/search?q=network+sniffing+with+python).

Comment: Thanks for being so fast. I updated the question given your suggestion.